# How to customize split-pattern for request parameter

Tags: spring-mvc, parameters, split, request

My problem is that I have the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/shiSolrClient/app/shi/search?q=xyz&fq=author:"Max, Muster"
```

I have a bean that maps these requestParameters:

```
public class SearchParams {

    private String q = "";
    private String[] fq;

    // getters goes here...
}
```

My Problem is that Spring automatically split the fq-parameter on the comma. So in my bean there are two Strings in fq:

```
String[0]: author:"Max
String[1]: Muster"
```

I don't want this behaviour. What I want is to tell Spring to split on '&'-tokens not on ','-tokens. E.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/shiSolrClient/app/shi/search?q=xyz&fq=author:"Max, Muster"&content:"someContent"
```

---

```
fq=     
String[0]: author:"Max, Muster"

String[1]: content:"someContent"
```

Can anyone tell me how to archive this in Spring MVC 3

My Controller is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(SearchParams searchParams, BindingResult bindResult, Model  
   model)  {

    SolrQuery solrQ = getBasicQuery(searchParams).setQuery(searchParams.getQ());
    for(String fq : searchParams.getFq()) {
        solrQ.setParam("fq", fq);
    }
    try {
        QueryResponse rsp = getSolrServer().query(solrQ);
        model.addAttribute("solrResults", transformResults(rsp.getResults(),
           rsp.getHighlighting(), searchParams, rsp));
        model.addAttribute("facetFields", transformFacets(rsp.getFacetFields(),
           rsp.getFacetDates(), searchParams));
        model.addAttribute("pagination", calcPagination(searchParams, 
           rsp.getResults()));
   ...
}
```

And my Spring-Config looks like this:

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Configure Apache Tiles for the view -->
<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
   <beans:property name="definitions">
          <beans:list>
      <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/layout/layouts.xml</beans:value>
      <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/hitlist/views.xml</beans:value>
      </beans:list>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
   <beans:property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext"/>
   <beans:property name="viewClass" 
           value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <beans:property name="basenames">
      <beans:list>
      <beans:value>global</beans:value>
      <beans:value>hitlist</beans:value>
      <beans:value>local/messages</beans:value>
      </beans:list>
   </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure 
          as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.shi.solrclient.web" />
```

Comment: Can you show us your controller code?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar problem trying to use a @RequestParameter with List (it kept getting chopped up at commas.

The solution I came up with was to use a WebRequest parameter in my controller method, which allows me to use request.getParameterValues("blar")

```
@RequestMapping(value = "search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(WebRequest req, BindingResult bindResult, Model  model)  {
    String[] searchParams = req.getParameterValues("fq")
```

Answer (score 1):

Registering a custom editor for String[] as proposed by Eugene does not work because String[] is converted to String by a CollectionToStringConverter before any custom editor usage.

In order to use another separator than comma (which is CollectionToStringConverter default behavior) you need to add your own custom converter as explained in [Spring MVC reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert-Spring-config).

```
<bean id="conversionService"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="example.MyCustomCollectionToStringConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

For implementing MyCustomCollectionToStringConverter, you can't extend CollectionToStringConverter since it is final but you can have a look to [its source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/CollectionToStringConverter.java) to create your own.

```
final class MyCustomCollectionToStringConverter implements ConditionalGenericConverter {

    private static final String DELIMITER = "&";

    private final ConversionService conversionService;

    public MyCustomCollectionToStringConverter(ConversionService conversionService) {
        this.conversionService = conversionService;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton(new ConvertiblePair(Collection.class, String.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        return ConversionUtils.canConvertElements(sourceType.getElementTypeDescriptor(), targetType, this.conversionService);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        if (source == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Collection<?> sourceCollection = (Collection<?>) source;
        if (sourceCollection.size() == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (Object sourceElement : sourceCollection) {
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(DELIMITER);
            }
            Object targetElement = this.conversionService.convert(sourceElement, sourceType.elementTypeDescriptor(sourceElement), targetType);
            sb.append(targetElement);
            i++;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: The `ConversionServiceFactoryBean` configuration as you mentioned it didn't work for me since the `MyCustomCollectionToStringConverter` has a parameterized instead of default constructor.
I just added in the `afterPropertiesSet()` method the `registry.addConverter(new MyCustomCollectionToStringConverter(this.getObject()));`

Answer (score 0):

Since noone has come up with a "proper" answer to this, your easiest option is probably to not get Spring to split the parameter at all, but instead to add the split logic in the getter method:

```
public class SearchParams {

    private String q = "";
    private String fq;

    public String[] getSplitFq() {
       // split and return the array
    }
}
```

This is probably easier than trying to persuade Spring to do it to your own specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @InitBinder annotation to configure array binding. Something like this should work:

```
@InitBinder("fq")
public void fqBinderInit(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.registerCustomEditor(String[].class, new StringArrayPropertyEditor("&"));
}
```

You can read more detailed explanation in [Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-ann-initbinder)