# Spring REST Controller understanding arrays of strings when having special characters like blank spaces or commas

Tags: java, arrays, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to write a Spring REST Controller getting an array of strings as input parameter of a HTTP GET request.

The problem arises when in the GET request, in some of the strings of the array, I use special characters like commas `,`, blank spaces  or forward slash `/`, **no matter if I URL encode the query part of the URL HTTP GET request**.

That means that the string "`1/4 cup ricotta, yogurt`" (**edit** which needs to be considered as a unique ingredient contained as a string element of the input array) in either this format:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/[...]/parseThis?[...]&ingredients=1/4 cup ricotta, yogurt
```

This format (please note the blank spaces encoded as `+` plus, rather than the hex code):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/[...]/parseThis?[...]&ingredients=1%2F4+cup+ricotta%2C+yogurt
```

Or this format (please note the blank space encoded as hex code `%20`):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/[...]/parseThis?[...]&ingredients=1%2F4%20cup%20ricotta%2C%20yogurt
```

is not rendered properly.

- The system does not recognize the input string as one single element of the array.
- In the 2nd and 3rd case the system splits the input string on the comma and returns an array of 2 elements rather than 1 element. I am expecting 1 element here.

The relevant code for the controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/parseThis",
        params = {
                "language",
                "ingredients"

        }, method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = HttpHeaders.ACCEPT + "=" + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity<CustomOutputObject> parseThis(
        @RequestParam String language,
        @RequestParam String[] ingredients){

    try {

        CustomOutputObject responseFullData = parsingService.parseThis(ingredients, language);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseFullData, HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO
    }

}
```

I need to perform HTTP GET request against this Spring controller, that's a requirement (so no HTTP POST can be used here).

**Edit 1:**

If I add `HttpServletRequest request` to the signature of the method in the controller, then I add a log statement like `log.debug("The query string is: '" + request.getQueryString() + "'");` then I am seeing in the log a line like `The query string is: '&language=en&ingredients=1%2F4+cup+ricotta%2C+yogurt'` (So still URL encoded).

**Edit 2:**

On the other hand if I add `WebRequest request` to the signature of the method, the the log as `log.debug("The query string is: '" + request.getParameter("ingredients") + "'");` then I am getting a string in the log as `The query string is: '1/4 cup ricotta, yogurt'` (So URL decoded).

I am using Apache Tomcat as a server.

Is there any filter or something I need to add/review to the Spring/webapp configuration files?

**Edit 3:**

The main problem is in the interpretation of a comma:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="test", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String renderTest(@RequestParam("test") String[] test) {
    return test.length + ": " + Arrays.toString(test);
    // /app/test?test=foo,bar => 2: [foo, bar]
    // /app/test?test=foo,bar&test=baz => 2: [foo,bar, baz]
}
```

Can this behavior be prevented?

Comment: Try to get request QueryString in your action method. How do you run it? I guess application server could be decoding url for you.

Comment: Good point, I've edited the question adding the relevant information. Thanks.

Comment: Look here http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding. I would first try to play around with this.

Comment: You can simplify this question and achieve [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you focus just on the fact that spring splits query parameter on comma when binding to a an array. The query encoding / spaces thing seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

The path of a *request parameter* to your *method argument* goes through *parameter value extraction* and then *parameter value conversion*. Now what happens is:

**Extraction**:

The parameter is [extracted as a single `String` value](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java#L207). This is probably to allow simple attributes to be passed as simple string values for later value conversion.

**Conversion**:

Spring uses [ConversionService](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/support/DefaultFormattingConversionService.java) for the value conversion. In its default setup [StringToArrayConverter is used](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToArrayConverter.java#L59), which unfortunately handles the string as comma delimited list.

**What to do**:

You are pretty much screwed with the way Spring handles single valued request parameters. So I would do the binding manually:

```
// Method annotations
public HttpEntity<CustomOutputObject> handlerMethod(WebRequest request) {
    String[] ingredients = request.getParameterValues("ingredients");
    // Do other stuff 
}
```

---

You can also check what [Spring guys have to say about this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7963).. and the [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998748/how-to-prevent-parameter-binding-from-interpreting-commas-in-spring-3-0-5).

Comment: Thanks for the details regarding the comma! I've solved it using `HttpServletRequest` and `getQueryString()` then splitting the encoded string with the pure comma `,` as separator, then safely decoding every string of the array (even if it was including a comma).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could register a [custom conversion service](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#core-convert-Spring-config) (from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22212196/603369)), but that seems like a lot of work. :) If it were me, I would ignore the declaration the `@RequestParam` in the method signature and parse the value using the incoming `request` object.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you try the following format:

```
ingredients=egg&ingredients=milk&ingredients=butter
```

Appending `&ingredients` to the end will handle the case where the array only has a single value.

```
ingredients=egg&ingredients=milk&ingredients=butter&ingredients
ingredients=milk,skimmed&ingredients
```

The extra entry would need to be removed from the array, using a `List<String>` would make this easier.

Alternatively if you are trying to implement a REST controller to pipe straight into a database with [spring-data-jpa](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/), you should take a look at [spring-data-rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/). Here is an [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/).

You basically annotate your repository with `@RepositoryRestResource` and spring does the rest :)

Comment: The problem I have is that one of those `ingredients` parameters might have a comma inside, they are not simple like `egg` or `milk`, they are "complex" like `1/4 cup ricotta, yogurt` and need to be considered as a unique ingredient (there you are not seeing `ricotta`, `yogurt` as 2 different ingredients)

Comment: I made a quick test app and `http://localhost:8080/?list=egg&list=milk,%20skimmed&list=butter` results in `{"egg", "milk, skimmed", "butter"}`.. Did you try it?

Comment: I am in the scenario where I have only 1 ingredient array element at least as complex as "`milk, skimmed`" expected to be processed as an array with 1 element and I am getting processed 2 elements divided using the comma `,` as separator. I have unsuccessfully tried this :(

Comment: It looks like it's deserialised as csv when there is a single instance of `ingredients`, but when you add more than one, each instance becomes a value in the array

Comment: I see the problem, how about adding an empty `&ingredients` to the end then removing it? `ingredients=milk,skimmed&ingredients` then in controller use a `List<String> ingredients` with `ingredients.remove(ingredients.size()-1)`

Comment: Yeah that might be a trick to solve the problem, however I have no control on the URL that someone is using when running an HTTP GET request, i.e. I can not ask them to add an empty parameter in the end :(

Comment: How about passing JSON?

Comment: I tried injecting the extra `ingredients` with an Interceptor but get `No modifications are allowed to a locked ParameterMap` so it looks like that is not an option :(

Comment: I can not use JSON objects because using an array of strings is a requirement :(

Comment: You can put an array of strings in a JSON object `{ingredients:["this", "is", "an", "array"]}`

Comment: A JSON containing just an array might be an option, a bit "ugly" but if it's the only way well that's still an option, could you elaborate more your answer with the details? Regarding the `WebRequest` with `.getParameterValues()` that is returning a decoded string so then I can not distinguish genuine commas from separator commas... If I use `HttpServletRequest` with `getQueryString()` then I get a URL encoded string so the comma separators are pure `,` making me able to distinguish them from the encoded `%20` commas, but then I need to elaborate the string and validate it...

Answer (score 0):

A solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6630552/2236236)

```
public String get(WebRequest req) {
    String[] ingredients = req.getParameterValues("ingredients");
    for(String ingredient:ingredients ) {
        System.out.println(ingredient);
    }
    ...
}
```

This works for the case when you have a single ingredient containing commas